# Namespaces inside a global namespace C#

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

So I have made a `.dll` containing some methods that I wish to use in another project. All is going well. I currently have the `.cs` files inside the `.dll` set out like this:

```
GeneralClass.cs
NetworkingClass.cs
TextProcessingClass.cs
```

And inside each of them is this:

```
namespace General // The name of each .cs file without 'Class'
{
    ...
}
```

So I will have these namespaces:

- `General`
- `Networking`
- `TextProcessing`

And I can access them in another project by doing:

```
using General;
using Networking;
...
```

This is all fine but I was wondering if there was a way to do it like this:

```
using MyDll.General;
using MyDll.Networking;
...
```

So everything would be under `MyDll`, just like `System` and all of its sub namespaces.

If you can help me, please post here.

Comment: you can declare your namespace like `namespace MyDll.General`, then you can use the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want namespace to be different why not to just do it? There are no restrictions on namespace to match file name (unlike some other languages).

```
namespace MyDll.General 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I never thought of doing it that way. I thought I would have to put the `General` and `Networking` namespaces inside of the `MyDll` namespace. I will accept your answer when I can.

Answer (score 7):

Define namespace as:

```
namespace MyDll.General
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you namespace like

```
namespace MyDll.General
{
    // define classes here
}

namespace MyDll.Networking
{
    // define classes here
}

namespace MyDll.TextProcessing
{
    // define classes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your dll project, just change

```
namespace General {}
```

to

```
namespace MyDll.General {}
```

and re-build it